# What is the point in using enum byte instead of int?

Tags: c#

my following question is about Enum. An enum use int as default type, however, it can be converted to byte. What is the point in converting an int enum to a byte?

```
public Enum SoccerType: byte

{
defenders=1, 
midfielder =2 , 
attackers = 3 
}
```

Comment: If you're dealing with a library that takes `byte` instead of `int` and you want an enum of values to pass then it might make sense then.

Answer (score 2):

Byte takes only 8 bits, which is 4 times less than default 32-bits-long integer. Memory optimization comes at the cost of lower range potential: number of options you can store withing a byte is significantly less. Try to find out why yourself.

Comment: Well, that is not the answer to the question. The main reason is if you want your enum to correspond to another type in your program and you need to explicitly cast between them.